# How to style parent li elements of headers using CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, html-heading

I would like to be able to set the property `list-style-type: none;` on all `li` elements that contain a major header (`<h1>`, `<h2>` and `<h3>`).

At first I tried this -

```
li h1,
li h2,
li h3 {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

But then I realised it wouldn't work, because it is setting the property on the headers, not the list elements.

How can I do this?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible with css. Have a look at this http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: you can't select parent element with pure css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a class to li items which contains header elements and set list-style to none.

For Example:

```
li.header {list-style:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

**CSS:**

```
    li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
   <ul>
       <li><h1>test1</h1></li>
       <li><h1>Test2</h1></li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: thanks for your advice hereafter i follow this rules , i am a beginner of stackoverflow my kind request please give the demo videos for how to post answer and how to ask question  etc.